# How to disable button on form submit exactly like stackoverflow ask question?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, button

I have seen stackoverflow ask question page they disable button until my postback event is finished when i post the question and redirect me to my question page... How to do this in asp.net/jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

to re-enable your button after a client side action has completes, such as AJAX:

```
$('#myform:input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: yes... as the attribute won't be persisted to the viewstate, the button will be enabled after postback again. one thing to be aware off: sometimes (especially with asp.net postbacks) there's no call of the submit-eventHandler

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is that you would have jquery add a client-side click event which disabled the button (i.e.  $('#controlName').attr("disabled", "disabled");  ).  What thing to remember is that you want to return TRUE from that method, so that the standard form post functionality will still work.

Something like:

```
$(function(){
   $('#controlName').click(function(){
      $('#controlName').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      return true;
   });
});
```

Comment: @Stephen what happens when my client side functionality finishes and goes server side will the button be still disabled.......

Comment: see my cmt at glennulars answer :)